# SSRS deselecting some values from multi-select paramter

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, multi-select, selectall

I have a report with a multi-select parameter.  The first time you run the report, everything works fine.

My issue is, if you choose the value `Select All` for `AssetTypes` and run the report - all good.  If you change one of the other parameters values (there are 4 others) and run the report again the `AssetTypes` list of values changes.  The `Select All` option is deselected and 2 other seemingly random values are also deselected??

I am printing the value count on the report as debugging.

```
=CStr(Parameters!AssetTypes.Count) + "-" + CStr(CountRows("ParamAssetTypes"))
```

The first time you run it - the values are 59 and 59
The second time you run (I don't even look at the AssetTypes list - I just run it again) the values are 56 and 59.

I am running VS2010 and SQL 2008

Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Seems like this should be tagged VS or SQL Server?

Comment: I am using VS/BIDS (isn't this the only SSRS dev environment??) to create the report but it runs on SSRS.  The behaviour is the same in the dev environment and on the reporting server

Comment: Do you have a default value on the multi-valued parameter that is being refreshed (and thus reset) when another parameter changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are feeding duplicated values into the Parameter's Available Values / Value Field.  SSRS gets very confused by this.

I would fix this will a GROUP BY or similar technique in the source Dataset.

Comment: This is the closest answer.  The query for the parameter was messed up - the Label and Value field values weren't at the same granularity (i.e. the Values were duplicated for some of the different Labels).  The data returned in the body of the report was always correct - but it did make for weird behaviour in the Parameter multi-select object.